# Can we Initialize dynamic string array 

Tags: c#-3.0

is there any way to Initialize dynamic string array .

```
public class CXmlFileHook
    {
        string  vAppname;
        string  vClassname;
        string  vIdmark;
        string  vExecname;
        string [] vApiName;
        string  vCtor;
```

```
    public CXmlFileHook()
    {
        this.vAppname = "Not Set";
        this.vIdmark = "Not Set";
        this.vClassname = "Not Set";
        this.vExecname = "Not Set";
        this.vApiName = new string[9] { "Not Set", "Not Set", "Not Set", "Not Set", "Not Set", "Not Set", "Not Set", "Not Set" ,"Not Set"};

        this.vCtor = "CXmlFileHook()";

    }
```

now i want the size of the string should increases dynamically and according to size it initializes it self is it possible????

Comment: Your question is unclear - please give more details. Also, why have you made it community wiki?

Comment: What's a dynamic string array? `List<string>`?

Answer (score 2):

Still not sure what you actually need to know, so here are a couple of answers to choose from :-)

Arrays in C# can't change its lengths. Use a collection class if you need dynamic collections, eg. `List<T>`.

A `List<T>` can be initialized using the same syntax:

```
this.vApiName = new List<string> 
  { 
    "Not Set", 
    "Not Set", 
    "Not Set", 
    "Not Set", 
    "Not Set", 
    "Not Set", 
    "Not Set", 
    "Not Set",
    "Not Set"
  };
```

If the length of the array does not change at runtime, you could use it. You don't need to specify the length of the array when declaring and initializing it at the same time. The length is determined by the compiler (it is still constant at runtime):

```
  this.vApiName = new string[] // <= no array-length, set to 9 by compiler
  { 
    "Not Set", 
    "Not Set", 
    "Not Set", 
    "Not Set", 
    "Not Set", 
    "Not Set", 
    "Not Set", 
    "Not Set",
    "Not Set"
  };
```

You don't need to initialize default values, if you just want to initialize with nulls (See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d%28VS.80%29.aspx)).

```
this.vApiName = new string[9]; // array containing 9 x null
```